# phonegap webview and static pages in one app

Tags: c#, asp.net, cordova, mobile, local-storage

I am working on a app which involves some dynamic pages which needs to be displayed inside a webview and some static pages which will be displayed if there is no internet connection is available. Can it be done in phonegap and how. I want to save the data to local storage when app is online and use that local storage when app is offline.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done with phone gap. You can check for connection with a Cordova plugin.

Comment: I am making the online pages in asp.net and they will work in webview so if I save localstorage in webview will it be available in html pages? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. But local storage works in webview :)